# Why IE showing Web page cannot be displayed message

Tags: c#, internet-explorer, windows-phone-8, webbrowser-control

I am developing a on-line shopping App in windows phone 8 ,for that we are using citruspay.com .We are using WebBrowser control for showing payment methods .As of now we  are facing one  issue with that Web-Browser control ,when we are loading the citruspay page in webview it shows a message  "Web page cannot be displayed" .if anyone faced this issue previously please help me .Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You must:

- Check the internet connection.
- Check the web page from another device.